# How to send an email using a SendGrid template with php api?

Tags: php, sendgrid

I have recently created a template in my SendGrid account which I'd like to use in my php application.

I'm currently sending emails using that account, but I have to code the html right inside my app, which doesn't provide the flexibility I need.

I couldn't find a method in the API to select the template I want to use and to replace the variables....

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Template_Engine/smtpapi.html

Answer (score 7):

After digging through GitHub I found this code snippet which works for me... I hope it helps you.
To use templates in v3 here is the code:

```
$mail->setTemplateId("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
// Put your template ID in from the web console after you create a template
```

Comment: Confirming it still works in 2020 :) and their doc is still bad :(

Comment: h t t p s://sendgrid.com/dynamic_templates/ui/d-bcb60ad64374437684aef4692baa6daf/versions/6a65de74-2f18-4c84-ad61-8568f897a21c/edit
......
6a65de74-2f18-4c84-ad61-8568f897a21c  <--- This should be the Template ID right?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the SendGrid PHP library: https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/blob/main/USE_CASES.md#transactional-templates

If not: [SendGrid: applying templates to WEB API pup curl method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33308146/sendgrid-applying-templates-to-web-api-pup-curl-method/)