# SendGrid: applying templates to WEB API pup curl method

Tags: php, api, curl, sendgrid

I'm using this code provided by Sendgrid itself

```
<?php
// use actual sendgrid username and password in this section
$url = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/'; 
$user = 'username'; // place SG username here
$pass = 'password'; // place SG password here
// grabs HTML form's post data; if you customize the form.html parameters then you will need to reference their new new names here
$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$subject = $_POST['subject']; 
$message = $_POST['message'];
// note the above parameters now referenced in the 'subject', 'html', and 'text' sections
// make the to email be your own address or where ever you would like the contact form info sent
$params = array(
    'api_user'  => "$user",
    'api_key'   => "$pass",
    'to'        => "xxxxxx@gmail.com", // set TO address to have the contact form's email content sent to
    'subject'   => "Contact Form Submission", // Either give a subject for each submission, or set to $subject
    'html'      => "<html><head><title> Contact Form</title><body>
    Name: $name\n<br>
    Email: $email\n<br>
    Subject: $subject\n<br>
    Message: $message <body></title></head></html>", // Set HTML here.  Will still need to make sure to reference post data names
    'text'      => "
    Name: $name\n
    Email: $email\n
    Subject: $subject\n
    $message",
    'from'      => "contact@xxxxxx.com", // set from address here, it can really be anything
  );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);
$request =  $url.'api/mail.send.json';
// Generate curl request
$session = curl_init($request);
// Tell curl to use HTTP POST
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
// Tell curl that this is the body of the POST
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
// Tell curl not to return headers, but do return the response
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// obtain response
$response = curl_exec($session);
curl_close($session);
// Redirect to thank you page upon successfull completion, will want to build one if you don't alreday have one available
header('Location: thanks.html'); // feel free to use whatever title you wish for thank you landing page, but will need to reference that file name in place of the present 'thanks.html'
exit();
// print everything out
print_r($response);
?>
```

But I don't understand how do i apply the templates i created in Sendgrid, neither I understand how to send HTML email instead of simple text...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
Dotenv::load(__DIR__);
$sendgrid_apikey = getenv('SG_KEY');
$sendgrid = new SendGrid($sendgrid_apikey);
$url = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/'; 
$pass = $sendgrid_apikey; 
$template_id = '<your_template_id>';
$js = array(
  'sub' => array(':name' => array('Elmer')),
  'filters' => array('templates' => array('settings' => array('enable' => 1, 'template_id' => $template_id)))
);
echo json_encode($js);
$params = array(
    'to'        => "elmer.thomas@sendgrid.com", 
    'toname'    => "Elmer Thomas",
    'from'      => "dx@sendrid.com",
    'fromname'  => "DX Team",
    'subject'   => "PHP Test", 
    'text'      => "I'm text!",
    'html'      => "<strong>I'm HTML!</strong>",
    'x-smtpapi' => json_encode($js),
  );
$request =  $url.'api/mail.send.json';
$session = curl_init($request);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer ' . $sendgrid_apikey));
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($session);
curl_close($session);
print_r($response);
```

Comment: thank you.. clear now... last question: how do I add the Sender's Name?

Comment: I've updated the example to include the sender's name. You can find all the parameters here: https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/mail.html

Comment: Can I know how to add merge fields of template?

Comment: @IshaS, I suggest you contact https://support.sendgrid.com. They will be happy to help.

Comment: Thanks @ElmerThomas

Comment: Gosh I hope this is still an active thread. QUESTION: How do I modify this code to send HTML?  FYI I can not figure out how to zip and unload the sendgrid. I don't know how to do the auto  install so I can't get to the autoload.php - So I skipped a few lines. It works without it. I just need to know how  to send HTML.

Answer (score 0):

First, I assume you already created your template here: https://sendgrid.com/templates and for this example's sake, the template looks like the following:

```
Hello :name,

<%body%>

With Best Regards,

Your Library Tester
```

Then, using [the official PHP SendGrid library](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php) and optionally [phpdotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv) for loading your credentials:

```
<?php      
Dotenv::load(__DIR__);
$sendgrid_apikey = getenv('SG_KEY');
$sendgrid = new SendGrid($sendgrid_apikey);

$email = new SendGrid\Email();

$templateId = '<your_template_id>';
$name = array('Elmer');

$email
    ->addTo('elmer.thomas@sendgrid.com')
    ->setFrom('dx@sendgrid.com')
    ->setSubject('Testing the PHP Library')
    ->setText('I\'m text!')
    ->setHtml('<strong>I\'m HTML!</strong>')
    ->addFilter('templates', 'enabled', 1)
    ->addFilter('templates', 'template_id', $templateId)
    ->addSubstitution(":name", $name)
;

$sendgrid->send($email);
```

Comment: i don't wanna us the library. it's old and has dependencies with Gruzzle

Comment: In that case, you can add the filter and substitution data using the SMTP API: https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/index.html directly using curl_setopt: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php.

Comment: With regards to the library, it's been recently updated this month and will continue to be, as we are in the process of improving all of our libraries. 
We have not moved the dependency from Guzzle just yet because it works well currently and our data shows that our PHP library is one of our most used libraries (in the top 3). Do you have any Guzzle replacement suggestions? Thanks for your feedback, we really appreciate it!

Comment: got it... i will try it next round, not the curl option it's fast and it works for my simple needs thanks!

Comment: the link is about JSON example...do you have an example in php? because i still don't get it... how come nobody expanded that example with a full example in php?